# SWIFT: Filling HTML input [type=“text”]

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, authentication, uiwebview

How to fill fields on an HTML form that is currently being presented in a web view?
The purpose of this application is meant to auto log-in into a website.
On basis of different tutorials I mostly copy-pasted a swift code but **mine does not work**. It would be great to get a hint what the mistake could be or even a complete different approach is very much appreciated.

The important parts of the [website](https://www.austrocontrol.at/flugwetter/) I want to login is built like this:

text-field *Username:*

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username:">
```

text-field *Password:*

```
<input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" maxlength="20" placeholder="Passwort:">
```

*LogIn-Button* (to submit the login):

```
<input type="submit" value="login" class="btn btn-default">
```

**My broken swift-code** of the *ViewController.swift*:

It just loads the website but *without filling in the username or password* and without submitting.

```
@IBOutlet weak var MyWebView: UIWebView!

func webViewDidFinishLoad(MyWebView: UIWebView) {

    // fill data
    let savedUsername = "USERNAME"
    let savedPassword = "PASSWORD"

    let fillForm = String(format: "document.getElementById('username').value = '\(savedUsername)';document.getElementById('password').value = '\(savedPassword)';")
    MyWebView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: fillForm)

    //submit form
    let deadlineTime = DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(1)
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: deadlineTime) {
        MyWebView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.value[\"login\"].submit();")
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = URL (string: "https://www.austrocontrol.at/flugwetter/")
    MyWebView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: url!))
    webViewDidFinishLoad(MyWebView: MyWebView)
}
```

I am not sure how to deal with this output I got from the Xcode-simulator but maybe it helps in a way:

```
[...] Starting WebFilter logging for process AustroControl Viewer
[...] _userSettingsForUser : (null)
[...] _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
[...] [MediaRemote] [AVOutputContext] WARNING: AVF context unavailable for +[MRAVOutputContext sharedAudioPresentationContext]_block_invoke
[...] [MediaRemote] [AVOutputContext] WARNING: AVF context unavailable for +[MRAVOutputContext createOutputContextWithUniqueIdentifier:]
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all: it's better to use `WKWebView`.

You can make a function that runs JavaScript in your `WebView` and fills the HTML form just before submitting it.

```
private func setWebViewValue(name: String, data: String) {
    let jsFunc = "document.getElementById(\"\(name)\").value = \"\(data)\""
    webView.evaluateJavaScript(jsFunc, completionHandler: nil)
}
```

Comment: is it possible to do it with swift-ui?