# Interacting and Submitting HTML form with JavaScript in Swift

Tags: javascript, html, swift

Trying to submit an HTML form / clicking a button from this web page: https://www.vegvesen.no/kjoretoy/Eie+og+vedlikeholde/skilt/personlig-bilskilt/sok-om-personlig-bilskilt

I've tried to use both .submit() and .click() with no success

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('personlig-kjennemerke').click();", completionHandler: nil)
```

So what I try to do is to fill in the text field with "REGNR" I then try to click the orange button to submit the form and access the information I am looking for.

I am able to fill in the textfield by using:

```
   webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('tegnkombinasjon').val    ue='\(plateNumber)'") { (value, error) in

        }
```

[Picture of the button I want to press and the text field I try to fill in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stjMB.png)

But since I'm not able to click the button programmatically I've tried to actually click it in a subview. The page then tells me I have to fill in the text field first even though I have programmatically.

So not only am I unable to click the button, but I'm also wondering how I can make the web page understand that the text field actually already contains text.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByName(\"sjekkreg\")[0].elements[2].click()")
```

Why by name? Because that form doesn't have an id.

Also I see your form has custom function to send that form:

```
pkCtrl.submit(mineFelt,sjekkreg)
```

Comment: Excuse me. I've forgot `getElementsByName` returns an array. Now try above code.

Comment: @Shift Ok, try my function now. This is terrible hard coding, but this form is too.

Comment: Yes that worked great! Only had to change to \"sjekkreg\" as it was from your previous suggestion. Do you have any idea how I can let the web page know that I actually added text to the field? Because I literally have to manually click the text field and add or remove one character for it to understand the rest is there.

Comment: @Shift do you mean `UITextField` or input in html form?

Comment: The input field above the orange button which you have helped me out with. It seems to have a "required" statement or something that checks if the user interacted with the input? I'm new to HTML so I really appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Check this out: [my answer for similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50651789/swift-filling-html-input-type-text/51817431#51817431)

Comment: I am able to add text to the input field using your code, but the website seem to have a value or check to see if the users actually "selected" the field and entered something, because when I click enter with your code. It doesn't recognise any string in the input even though it's there with a message saying: "Add an input to the field". I have to manually select the input field and add or remove a character for it to acknowledge the string in the input field. Only then can I click enter which leads me to where I want to go.